# Porn parody of Lord of the Rings where the protagonist is from a Hobbit parody race that will "try anything"

Tags: story-identification, movie, fan-fiction

When I was in grad school (around 2006-2007 in Pittsburgh, PA), someone in my social group (that I have since lost touch with) was discussing watching a porn parody film of *Lord of the Rings* where the female protagonist came from a race analogous to hobbits, but with a name like "Trybits" or "Tribits" with the main character at some point cheerfully proclaiming a line like "I'm a Tribit. We'll try anything!"

I remember absolutely nothing else about the film, but it's stuck in my head, so I'm hoping that by identifying it, I can exorcise it.

Comment: FWIW, https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/lets-talk-about-story-id-requests-for-erotica/11442?r=SearchResults#11442 but I still support people who want to downvote.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Erotic ≠ pornographic

Comment: @valorum Although the line is (purposefully) subjective.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Lord of the G-Strings: The Femaleship of the String](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0323108/) (2003)

> A diminutive and seductive **Throbbit** has been entrusted with the task of destroying the all-powerful G-String that can grant its possessor untold powers.

[Relevant quote](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0323108/quotes?ref_=m_tt_trv_qu):

> **Dildo Saggins**: Actually, the Throbbits were trisexuals. They'd try anything, the horny little bastards

Comment: Found it online, and wow... it's really, really bad. Well, at least now I can put it out of my mind.